# Calculating Probability of Die Rolls with a single reroll

Tags: statistics, dice

I am trying to figure out the odds of success for this problem, but keep running into issues around the ability to reroll one die.

Scenario:  I am making two rolls of special dice.  I am allowed to reroll one die in the first set, and in total I need 3 "successes"

Set 1, where I am allowed to reroll one die, has the following dice:
A Die with success on 1 of 6 faces
A Die with success on 2 of 6 faces
A Die with success on 3 of 6 faces

Set 2, where no reroll is allowed, has the following dice:
A Die with sucess on 1 of 6 faces
Two Dice with successes on 2 of 6 faces

I need a total of 3 successes among all of the dice rolled (with the reroll replacing the result of the rolled die).

Calculating the odds of each group succeeding is easy (disregarding reroll 6/216 or 2.8% and 4/216 or 1.85% respectively).  I am at a total loss for how to figure in that reroll for the larger problem.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:  Three success must happen among all six dice, the sets are just defining where a reroll can happen.  You can choose which die in the first set to reroll (but obviously if it rolled a success and you reroll, the success is ignored and the new result is used).

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Am I rolling both sets or am I to chose between them?  for set $1$, can I pick the die I want to re-roll? (obviously, we pick the one with three successes if that one was a fail the first time, yes?)

Comment: If you can choose the die to re-roll, clearly you choose the fail with the highest success probability.  so, just run through all the cases.  there aren't many so case by case analysis works just fine.

Comment: To add to lulu's comment: You've already got the probability of hitting S S S (S=success), now add to that the probability of first getting F S S and then getting S on rerolling die 1. After that, add the relevant probability when you first get S F S, and then when you first get S S F. Done.

Comment: I found it a lot easier to literally write a program and run 200 million attempts at this.  I got the odds to be around 38.8%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulation may indeed be faster, though a systematic calculation of the probabilities is possible.

For the first set of dice the possible outcomes are as follows, where for example `S   F   F(S)  2  6/216` means success on the first die and failure on the second and failure on the third with the third rerolled for a success with an outcome of $2$ successes with probability $\frac16 \times \frac46 \times \frac36 \times \frac36 = \frac{6}{216}$

```
Pattern     Successes Probability
S   S   S       3      6/216
S   S   F(S)    3      3/216
S   S   F(F)    2      3/216
S   F(S)S       3      4/216
S   F(F)S       2      8/216
S   F   F(S)    2      6/216
S   F   F(F)    1      6/216
F(S)S   S       3      5/216
F(F)S   S       2     25/216
F   S   F(S)    2     15/216
F   S   F(F)    1     15/216
F   F(S)S       2     20/216
F   F(F)S       1     40/216
F   F   F(S)    1     30/216
F   F   F(F)    0     30/216
```

to give probabilities of the number of successes on the first set of dice

```
Successes   Probability
    0       30/216
    1       91/216
    2       77/216
    3       18/216
```

Similarly for the second set of dice

```
Pattern     Successes   Probability
S   S   S       3        1/54
S   S   F       2        2/54
S   F   S       2        2/54
S   F   F       1        4/54
F   S   S       2        5/54
F   S   F       1       10/54
F   F   S       1       10/54
F   F   F       0       20/54
```

to give

```
Successes   Probability
    0       20/54
    1       24/54
    2        9/54
    3        1/54
```

Combine the first and second sets of dice to give

```
Successes   Probability
    0        600/11664
    1       2540/11664
    2       3994/11664
    3       3057/11664
    4       1216/11664
    5        239/11664
    6         18/11664
```

And so the probability of at least $3$ successes in total is then $\frac{4350}{11664} = \frac{755}{1944} \approx 0.38837$,  similar to the result of your simulation

Comment: well, I'm happy I built my simulations right.  For some reason I kept getting stuck when doing this by hand on figuring out all the die rolls as an entire group, not the two groups of three (which is simpler).  TY